# Is there any solutions for Laravel Datatables export CSV or XLSX takes too long times until my browser crash (5000+ rows)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatables, export-to-csv

I want to ask why when I try to export data from data tables into CSV or xlsx format takes a very long time (sometimes it crash my browser). I'm using datatables clientside, 5100 rows and using ajax to call its data from laravel controller. Is there anyone knows about it? thank you before.